# How to animate widget after the app is launched

Tags: animation, widget, flutter, rendering

I want to animate my container height after launching the application (after the widget tree is rendered and shown on screen). For example, animate height from 86 to 210.

What I have tried:

```
class MyAppState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  double appBarHeight = 86.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => animate());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedContainer(
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            height: appBarHeight,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.brush),
                  onPressed: () {
                    animate();
                  },
                ),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void animate(){
    setState(() {
      if (appBarHeight == 210.0) appBarHeight = 86.0;
      else appBarHeight = 210.0;
    });
  }
}
```

But it does not work, because widget is animated before appearing on screen. I see white screen while app is launching and then my widget appears on screen with a final height.

In Android for this purpose we can use `addOnLayoutChangeListener()`.

Is there an analogue of `addOnLayoutChangeListener()` in Flatter?

Comment: I doubt is there such method in flutter. Here is lifecycle methods for `StatefulWidget` - https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/. But I didn't see which of them you can use

Comment: if you increase the duration of the animation, does it works?   Duration(milliseconds: 400)

Comment: Your code has no apparent issues, the duration of 400 ms is too small to notice , increase your duration it will work just fine I tested it.

Comment: @diegoveloper It works with bigger duration, but I think it isn't a solution. How much should I increase the duration? The duration = while app is launching + animation duration? But it is a diferent time for diferent phone. I want to start animaion with any duration after the widget is laid out.

Comment: if I run your sample on my iOS simulator it just works fine, the animation appears at the beginning

Comment: @diegoveloper On my Android Nexus 5X and 5 it doesn't work fine, but with native kotlin works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, looks like it's an issue on Android, I tested on iOS and the animation runs at the beginning.

You can try this workaround :

```
  _startAnimation(_) async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
      animate();
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_startAnimation);
    }
```